# Typescript generics with factory function

Tags: typescript

I have a class that I want to extend with a factory class that will return the correct class based on the input.

```
class Base<S> {
  prop: S;
  base() { }
}

class A<S> extends Base<S> {
  a() { }
}

class B<S> extends Base<S> {
  b() { }
}


interface TypeA {
  propA: any;
}

interface TypeB {}

function isTypeA(params: TypeA | TypeB): params is TypeA {
  return (params as TypeA).propA !== undefined;
}

function factory(params: TypeA): typeof A;
function factory(params: TypeB): typeof B;
function factory(params: TypeA | TypeB): typeof A | typeof B {
  if (isTypeA(params)) {
    return A;
  } else {
    return B;
  }
}

const param: TypeA = { propA: {} };
const param2: TypeB = {};

class Test extends factory(param) { }
```

In addition to that, I need to pass a generics all the way up. How can I pass the generic from the factory function to the `Base` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
class Test<T> extends factory(param)<T> { }
```

Or, if you don't want `Test` to be generic:

```
class Test extends factory(param)<string>()
```

Comment: I think the point is that `factory` should return `typeof A<typeof param>` which is syntactically incorrect in typescript, but that is the desired effect. ie `class Test extends factory(param)<typeof param> { }`

Comment: You think so? I didn't understand it that way. I think that the type of `param` and the type parameter of `A` (or `B`) are not related, but of course, he/she can clarify that

Comment: I might have misunderstood, OP should clarify :)